# How to use this code as Unobtrusively?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use this code as Unobtrusively? To keep content and Behaviour separate.

```
    <a href="nojavascript.html" onclick="functionName(); return false;" 
onkeypress="functionName(); return false;">Link text</a>
```

Comment: You should use javascript:void(0) inside the href instead of returning false on onClick

Comment: @the_drow that completely defeats the point of the question, the link should work **without** Javascript, not require it.

Comment: the_drow: No, absolutely not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write it like this:

```
<a href="nojavascript.html">Link text</a>
```

Then use jQuery's [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) like this:

```
$("a[href$='nojavascript.html']").bind("click keypress", function() {
  functionName();
  return false;
});
```

Or alternatively, give it a class like this:

```
<a class="noJS" href="nojavascript.html">Link text</a>
```

And use a [`.class` selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) like `$("a.noJS")` instead to be a bit cleaner (or, if it's unique, use an ID).